# Android Scrollview inside constraint layout is not working. How do i fix this?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview, constraintlayout-guideline

Adding a scroll view inside a constraint layout is not working. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Here is the layout for your reference. Even after having one child linear layout inside a Scroll view is also not working. It overlaps out of the toolbar. They've also used constraint layout guidelines and it's a bit confusing. Kindly help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineleft"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineright"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="Hello, Anderson!"
            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/subTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="Have a nice day!"
            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color_gray"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/constranTopContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineright"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subTitle">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrAssignedItem"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lnrCompletedItem"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_purblue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_gradiant_purblue" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_assigned_icon" />

                    </FrameLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:text="Assigned Items"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            />

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:id="@+id/assignedItem"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="124"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrCompletedItem"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lnrAssignedItem"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">



                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_gradiant_green" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_completed_item_icon" />

                    </FrameLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:text="Completed Items"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:id="@+id/completedItem"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="54"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/lnrPendingItem"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lnrNewlyClosedItem"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_orange"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_gradiant_orange" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_pending_icon" />

                    </FrameLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:text="Pending Items"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            />

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:id="@+id/pendingItem"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="24"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrNewlyClosedItem"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lnrPendingItem"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_blue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_gradiant_blue" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_newly_created_icon" />

                    </FrameLayout>




                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:text="Newly Created"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            />

                        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/newItem"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="14"
                            android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineright"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constranTopContainer">



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/physicalverification"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_verifcation_icon" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Physical Verification"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_verifcation_icon" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Sync Up"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/home_report"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_report_icon" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:text="Report"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineright"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container2">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/home_help"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_help_icon" />


                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:text="Help"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/round_primary" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_download_icon" />

                </FrameLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Downloads"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/home_Profile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_profile_icon" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:text="My Account"
                    android:textColor="@color/side_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please add images with what you need and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Make your scroll view fill height and align bottom to parent bottom hopefully it will work.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineright"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineleft"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelineTop">
```